# Dojo ConfirmDialog hiding cancel button

Tags: javascript, dialog, dojo, dijit.dialog

I have a dojo `ConfirmDialog` as below:

```
this.myDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
                   title: "My Dialog",
                   content: "Do you want to continue?",
                   class: "confirmDialog",
                   closable: false
                });

// change button labels
this.myDialog.set("buttonOk","Yes");
this.myDialog.set("buttonCancel","No");

// register events
this.myDialog.on("execute", function() { 
                              self.continueSomething() 
                            });
```

Later on based on some condition, I am updating the `ConfirmDialog` dynamically as below:

```
this.myDialog.set("title", "New Title");
this.myDialog.set("content", "Its too late. Press ok to re-route.");
this.myDialog.set("buttonOk","Ok");
```

At this stage, I do not have any function for the `Cancel` button. How do I hide it?

None of the following work:

```
this.myDialog.cancelButton.hide();
//or
this.myDialog.cancelButton.set("display", "none");
//or 
this.myDialog.cancelButton.set("display", none);
```

I am able to disable it as:

```
this.myDialog.cancelButton.set("disabled", true);
```

But that does not look correct. I want to hide the `Cancel` button completely.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cancelButton` is a `button Dijit` , if you want to hide / show this last ,
you've to access it's domNode by smply typing `this.myDialog.cancelButton.domNode`
and use the [`dojo/dom-style`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-style.html) to hide /show as below

```
let cancelBtnDom = this.myDialog.cancelButton.domNode;
domStyle.set(cancelBtnDom, 'display', 'none');
```

see below working wnippet (disable enable using external button )

```js
require(["dijit/ConfirmDialog", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ConfirmDialog, domStyle){
    myDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
        title: "My ConfirmDialog",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 300px"
    },"dialog");
    
    let cancelBtn = myDialog.cancelButton.domNode;
    
    let switchBtn = document.getElementById("switch");
    
    switchBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
     let display = domStyle.get(cancelBtn, "display") !== "none" ?  "none" : "";
     console.log(display);
      domStyle.set(myDialog.cancelButton.domNode, 'display', display);
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="claro">
  <div class="dialog"></div>
  <button onclick="myDialog.show();">show</button>
  <button id="switch" >enable/Disable cancel button</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! could you please check my new question around this. On drawing user's attention.