# Dojo declarative ConfirmDialog hiding cancel button

Tags: javascript, dialog, dojo

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274566/dojo-confirmdialog-hiding-cancel-button) shows how to hide a cancel button on a programmatic `ConfirmDialog` in Dojo.

How to do the same thing, i.e. hiding the `Cancel` button, if the `ConfirmDialog` is declarative as below in a HTML template:

```
<div class="confirmDialog" 
     data-dojo-type="dijit/ConfirmDialog" 
     data-dojo-attach-point="confirmDialogAttachPoint" 
     data-dojo-props="title:'MyDialog', content:'Some Content', closable:false" 
     data-dojo-attach-event="onExecute:doSomething">
</div>
```

Doing the following in `postCreate` function of the corresponding widget works:

```
domStyle.set(this.confirmDialogAttachPoint.cancelButton.domNode, "display", "none");
```

However, I want to know/learn if this could be done declaratively in the HTML file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just adding a css to your widget css will hide your button :

```
.dijitDialogPaneActionBar .dijitButton:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

See below snippet :

```js
require(["dijit/ConfirmDialog", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Button"]);
```

```css
    .dijitDialogPaneActionBar .dijitButton:nth-child(2) {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {
    isDebug: true,
    async: true,
    parseOnLoad: true
  }
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="claro">

  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/ConfirmDialog" data-dojo-id="myDialog" title="dialog">
    Hi !
  </div>

  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myDialog.show();">
    Show me!
</button>
</body>
```

Comment: So there is no way to do it inline in the HTML itself.. thanks!

Comment: here you have to extends and create your custumied confirmDialog,  ( using props ) but you have to extend other dijit , (too long to do)